# Type deduce a template functions return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-deduction

I am writing a template function which returns the difference of consecutive elements of a vector using `std::minus`.

At present I have the following code:

```
template <typename T>
auto diffs(std::vector<T> &nums)
{
    typedef decltype(std::minus<T>()) diffType;
    std::vector<diffType> differences;
    differences.reserve(nums.size() - 1);
    auto test = std::back_inserter<std::vector<decltype (std::minus<T>())>>;
    std::transform(++begin(nums), end(nums), begin(nums), std::back_inserter(differences), std::minus<T>());

    return differences;
}
```

and am calling it using

```
void test()
{
    auto values = std::vector<int>{ 1,2,4,6,89,1456 };
    auto differences = diffs(values);
}
```

When I compile this I get:

```
binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

How do I declare my `typedef` so that it works properly with my `back_inserter`?

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
decltype(std::minus<T>())
```

Is asking for the type of default constructing a `minus<T>`, which is just `minus<T>`. What you'd wanted is what happens when you invoke it:

```
decltype(std::minus<T>()(nums[0], nums[0]))
```

Or you could use a type trait instead:

```
std::invoke_result_t<std::minus<T>, T const&, T const&>
```